# Keycloak: Customize well-known OpenID Configuration

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, openid, keycloak-connect

After configuring various realms, I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to customize the "/.well-known/openid-configuration" endpoint for each realm.

The goal is to modify fields such as:

- grant_types_supported
- ** _ alg_values_supported
- ** _ auth_methods_supported
  and in general the fields present in the json.

I couldn't find anything in the official documentation or internet in general

Comment: Why you need to modify that? That's for discovery, so service provider will know all available options and then it can decide which option will be used.

Comment: ok, those "well-known" are all the supported options keycloak's manage. But for example in my Realm for  "grant_types_supported" field, I'll never have an "implicit" flow and I would filter it. Is this principle wrongs?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. Discovery is not to list what you have, but is there to list what your IDP can offer. You are not supposed to manage values in the discovery on your own.